# Show Empty textbox if model has zero value AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, show-hide, angular-ng-if

I have textbox in my view as following :

```
<input id="line1 " name="line1" ng-readonly="locked == true" ng-show="lineData[0].line != 0" ng-model="lineData[0].line" class="form-control" type="text" required />
```

I just want to show an empty textbox if `lineData[0].line = 0` else it shows the actual value. How can acheive this? Can anyone help me to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: put more details. ng-show="lineData[0].line != 0" in HTML and you are saying that you want to show when "lineData[0].line = 0". It is not clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why you are using ng-show="lineData[0].line != 0".. you need clear textbox or hide textbox..
clear code.

```
 $scope.lineData[0].line = $scope.lineData[0].line != 0 ? $scope.lineData[0].line : null;
```

Comment: In controller I have as  $scope.lineData = data;

Comment: after $scope.lineData = data; put this code $scope.lineData[0].line = $scope.lineData[0].line != 0 ? $scope.lineData[0].line : null;